# Number Sequence With Gaps

Tags: oracle, sequence

In an Oracle PLSQL function I want to generate a special kind of sequence number. It starts with `00000001`, but when `00899999` is reached, I want to have `01000001` as its next number. This pattern repeats when `01899999` is reached: The next number then should be `02000001`.

To put it another way: My goal is to skip the numbers in the sequence in the range between `##900000` and `##999999`, where `##` denote two digits.

How can this be done on an Oracle database?

Comment: I think your design and "requirement" are fatally flawed.  Oracle sequences are NEVER guaranteed to be "gapless".  Suppose you "pull" a sequence, but then for whatever reason decide to roll back the transaction.  That sequence number is lost forever.  Or suppose the database is shut down or the pool is flushed due to memory constraints.  All unused sequences in the cache are lost.  And if you try to create your own sequence mechanism by looking at the max of some number in a table, you will necessarily have to serialize it's use, making it unsutible for a multi-user system.

Comment: @EdStevens Thanks for your thoughts on this! Please keep in mind that I have never asked for a sequence that has gaps ONLY in a certain range. My requirement is that I have a sequence which does not produce numbers in a certain range, but otherwise to act the same (or similar) as an Oracle sequence. Pulling numbers as max from a table or to use a table on its own for storing the current sequence's value needs to be guarded by a locking-mechanism to make it work in a multi-user environment, as I have pointed out in the comments below to RDFozz's answer.

Comment: @EdStevens RDFozz solved this by a neat SELECT FOR UPDATE.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an algorithm:

- Add 1 to previous number;
- if (current number + 100000) % 1000000 = 0, add 100001 to current number.

So:

- 899998 + 1 = 899999; (100000 + 899999) % 1000000 = 999999; return 899999.
- 899999 + 1 = 900000; (100000 + 900000) % 1000000 = 0; 900000 + 100001 = 1000001; return 1000001
- 1000001 + 1 = 1000002; (100000 = 1000002) % 1000000 = 100002; return 1000002
  ...
- 1899998 + 1 = 1899999; (100000 + 1899999) % 1000000 = 999999; return 1899999
- 1899999 + 1 = 1900000; (100000 + 1900000) % 1000000 = 0; 1900000 + 100001 = 2000001; return 2000001
- and so on.

One implementation:

- `CREATE TABLE myNumSeq (lastNum int); INSERT INTO myNumSeq (0);`
- Create a function, `fn_GetNextNum()`, that works something like this:

  ```
  DECLARE @theNum int;
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  SELECT TOP 1 @theNum = lastNum + 1 FROM myNumSeq FOR UPDATE;
  IF (@theNum + 100000) % 1000000 = 0
  BEGIN
      SET @theNum = @theNum + 100001;
  END;
  UPDATE myNumSeq SET lastNum = @theNum;
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
  RETURN @theNum;
  ```

Add error handling as appropriate. I haven't used Oracle regularly in about 18 years, so please consider the above pseudocode. I leave the Oracle-specific details (can't recall if it has both procedures and functions, or the return mechanism used for something like this if it only has procedures) to someone familiar with that.

I'm sure this could be written more concisely, but for single-record additions it should work fine. If you're adding records in bulk, using a variation on a number table would probably be quicker than a function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have clarified the question. Unfortunately the pattern repeats when `01899999` is reached. Also I am looking for some implementation details in PLSQL.

Comment: There seems to be some logic issue in your explanation? first time you want to go from 899999 to 1000001, skipping 1000000 and next time from 1899999 you wish to go to 2000000. Right? You probably need to write a function with two sequences that generate what you need and return the value to the caller. One of those would start at 1 and when you reach 899999, re-starts at 1. Another one that starts at 0 and increments by 1000000 when first sequence resets. I'd caution that this function will likely limit your performance scaling.

Comment: @Raj: Thanks for pointing that out. Its actually starting with `...0001` every time.

Comment: The formula I specified took into account that this should work at 899999, 1899999, 2899999, etc. - that's why I'm using modulo.  FYI, added pseudocode - haven't used Oracle in ages, so not sure of the specifics for making it a function.

Comment: @Raj - that seems like a perfectly valid answer of its own. Why don't you add it?

Comment: Ok I'll do that.

Comment: @mruether - I usually make the allowance for something to be rolled back, so I just hand-waved the full transaction thing originally. Updated with transaction (and the `SELECT` has `FOR UPDATE` added).

Comment: Wow, that is neat! Thanks a lot for continuously improving your solution!

Comment: @RDFozz Is it OK if I update your post with actual PLSQL for Oracle after I have implemented your suggestion? It would be a simple transform to Oracle syntax, but you Ansatz for this solution would remain.

Comment: Absolutely! The goal is not to just help you, but the next person with a similar question.